# MySQL: Compare comma separated values with values in different rows

Tags: mysql

I have following requirements.

I have two tables T1 and T2 like

## Table T1

```
Product     Geography
P1          G1
P2          G1
P2          G2
```

## Table T2

```
Product     Geography
P1          G1, G2
P2          G1, G2
```

I want a query to get data from table T2 if comma separated Geography have exactly matching records in T1. If there are less or more geographies in any table than it should not return that row. Sequence of geographies in T2 is not fixed. So return of that query from above example will be:

```
Product     Geography
P2          G1, G2
```

Answer (score 1):

Join on concating values

```
SELECT t2.Product,t2.geography FROM t2
JOIN 
(SELECT  t1.Product,GROUP_CONCAT(t1.geography ORDER BY t1.Geography SEPARATOR ', ') as concatgeo FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.product)x
ON t2.Geography=x.concatgeo AND t2.Product=x.Product
```

Comment: maybe `SEPARATOR ', '` shall be used because of white space between values?

Comment: Sequence of geographies in T2 is not fixed, it can be `G2, G1` or `G1, G3, G2`. So I don't think ORDER BY in group_concat will work for me.

Comment: @AnoopVerma Do you have some sort of order common to both tables,like a primary key?

Comment: No there is nothing common in both the tables. T1 is real table in DB while  in T2 I am getting the data from user, so if T1 already have data for any record in T2 than I need to inform user that this record is already present. I am thinking to define order in T2, than your query will work. thank you.

Comment: @AnoopVerma The only way is to break the concated values and reorder them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
firstTable.Product,
firstTable.geographies
FROM
(
   SELECT 
    Product,
    REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(Geography),' ','') AS geographies
   FROM T1
   GROUP BY Product) firstTable

INNER JOIN 

(
   SELECT 
    Product,
    REPLACE(Geography,' ','') AS geographies
   FROM T2 ) secondTable

ON firstTable.Product = secondTable.Product
WHERE firstTable.geographies = secondTable.geographies;
```

**Note:** I've replaced the spaces using `REPLACE` function just to ensure the two queries from two tables generate the same string

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79146/1/0)

**TEST (If you cannot access sqlfiddle):**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Geography` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('1', 'P1', 'G1');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('2', 'P2', 'G1');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('3', 'P2', 'G2');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t2`;
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Geography` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('1', 'P1', 'G1, G2');
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('2', 'P2', 'G1, G2');
```

Running the above query on this test data you will get output like below:

```
Product geographies
P2         G1,G2
```